# Django admin no error- hides section on advanced lookup

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have got this query working fine.

```
Variation.objects.filter(size__stock__stock__in=[1,2]).filter(product__tag__name__in=['Basics', 'This']).distinct('product').count()
```

However, I cannot get it to work in my admin.py to display this count of how single products are counted in the query.

```
class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
...
    def male_only_count(self, obj):
        return obj.product_set.filter(gender=1).filter(size__stock__stock__in=[1,2]).distinct('product').count()
```

What I am trying to do:

Attempting to find> Items with tag name with 'XYZ', that have the stock level '3'.

The lookup would be like Stock level > Size > Variation > Product > Tag

**My models:**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField ("Name", max_length=400)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, db_index=True, blank=False, null=False)
    variation = models.CharField (max_length=80, blank=True)

class Size(models.Model):
    variation = models.ForeignKey(Variation, blank=False, null=False)
    size = models.CharField("Size", max_length=100, blank=True)

Stock_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'In Stock'),
    (2, 'Low Stock'),
    (3, 'Out of Stock'),
    (4, 'Discontinued'),
)

class Stock(models.Model):
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, blank=False, null=False)
    stock = models.IntegerField(choices=Stock_CHOICES)
    created = models.DateTimeField("Created", auto_now_add=True)
```

I don't get an error- admin just does not load the fields relating to tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I see is that you are filtering for gender=1 and I don't see a gender field in the Product model. I'll just assume that it's there and you left it out for brevity.

In your working example, you are filtering Variation objects with:

```
filter(size__stock__stock__in=[1,2])
```

In your admin example, you are trying to filter Products with the same definition yet Product does not have a size attribute. Try this instead:

```
filter(variation__size__stock__stock__in=[1,2])
```

To get your count of distinct Variation objects from this queryset, you'll need to use aggregation:

```
.aggregate(num_variations=Count('variation', distinct=True))
```

Putting it all together:

```
return obj.product_set.filter(gender=1).filter(variation__size__stock__stock__in=[1,2]).aggregate(num_variations=Count('variation', distinct=True))['num_variations']
```

Comment: Thanks Rob- however I'd like it to return 1 variation result per product. How is this achieved? My attempt did not work: return obj.product_set.filter(variation__size__stock__stock__in=[1,2]).distinct('product').count()

Comment: @Ycon - to get your count of the related Variation objects from the filtered Product queryset, you need to use aggregate. I've updated the answer.